# достать UID карты при чтении порта с arduino в visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino, arduino-uno, serialport

Создала проект в Visual Studio для чтения номера смарткарты через последовательный порт. В качестве картридера беру собранный из RFID RC522 модуля и платы Arduino UNO R3. Пишу на C#. Информация выводится, как на картинке. Подскажите, как отсюда достать UID карты? Видела подобные вопросы, но люди писали в Arduino IDE, а в VS библиотеку MFRC522 подключить не получается(
Прикрепляю код:

```
    class SerialPortProgram
    {
        // Create the serial port with basic settings
        private SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM6",
          9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new SerialPortProgram();
        }

    private SerialPortProgram()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data:");
        port.Open();
        while (true)
        {
            port.DataReceived += new
              SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        }
        
    }

        private void port_DataReceived(object sender,
          SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(port.ReadLine());
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите код...

Comment: Проблему исправила, выводит информацию структурированно, но теперь мне нужно вытащить UID карты. Прикреплю код и вывод консоли

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решила путём проверки наличия в полученных строках подстроки "Card UID:" методом Contains. Далее просто вырезаю нужный мне номер карты и сохраняю в строковую переменную :)